# is subclass re-synthesized variable the same as its superclass

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

I learned that give two class subA and A, when subclass access superclass property directly(without super call) need some workaround, below is one of them I found

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@end

@interface subA : A
@end

@implementation subA
@synthesize name = _name;
- (void)setName(NSString *)name {
    _name = name;
}
@end
```

the question is that @synthesize in the subA looks as if it re-synthesized a new iVar, is that true?

Comment: `_name` in `A` is not visible to `subA` and by synthesizing it again, you are creating a new ivar in `subA`. You should use `[super setName:]`.

Comment: @Sulthan yes, after a few more investigation, you are right, it created a new iVar